# Use one control multiple times in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I have is few dropDownLists in few different templates of FormView.

And of course I can't get access to any of those.
What I want to do is get the same behavior for every DropdownList.
Is there any way to declare that DropDownList globally and reuse it or it should be done somehow with FindControl?

Comment: You can put the `DropDownList` (and other controls that you need) into one `UserControl`. However, you should not share the **same** control but only the type. If you really need you could use the same `DataSource` which can be stored in `Cache`. But i would do that only if it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

User control declarative syntax is very similar to syntax used to create an ASP.NET Web page.

The primary differences are that the user controls use an @ Control directive in place of an @ Page directive, and that the user controls do not include the html, body, and form elements around the content.

[MSDN/creating usercontrol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(v=vs.85).aspx)